# How to dockerize to access on-premises NFS file from ECS Fargate (Linux/Windows)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I need to access the on-premises NFS file from docker orchestration on ECS Fargate (Linux/Windows). On-premises and AWS are connected via Direct Connect. I am unsure if the docker on ECS Fargate task can be mounted NFS/Samba to access NFS file.
Question:

1. If I choose to mount AWS EFS on docker and sync data to this volume from on-premises via DataSync - Is this solution acceptable?
2. Any other AWS service that can be used to pick NFS file and consume using docker container orchestrated on ECS Fargate ?

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_data_volumes.html) stated that only these volumes are allowed in ECS:

1. Amazon EFS volumes
2. FSx for Windows File Server volumes
3. Docker volumes
4. Bind mounts

So it currently does not support on-premises NFS file.

Another solution is to mount the EFS on-prem. Then you alter whatever the existing workload on-prem to write to the EFS, instead of (or in addition to) the current NFS.